# How to permute in Prolog the elements of a list composed of sub-list and atoms

Tags: prolog, permutation

Let us consider lists such as `L=[[7,3,4],9,[4,5],[1,3,5],4]` where components could be lists or atoms. How to produce this type of permutation results:

```
R = [[7, 3, 4], 9, [4, 5], [1, 3, 5], 4] 
R = [[7, 4, 3], 9, [5, 4], [1, 3, 5], 4] 
R = [[7, 4, 3], 9, [4, 5], [1, 5, 3], 4] 
....
```

In fact, we would like to have all the possible permutations of the sub-lists of `L` while the atom should remain unchanged.

I wrote a classical predicate `permutation(OriginalList,PermutedList)`, and an `allperm` predicate that apply the `maplist` function to this permutation predicate:

```
permutation([],[]).

permutation(L,[T|Q]) :-
    select(T,L,L1),
    permutation(L1,Q).

/*L is the list to permute, R the result*/
allperm(L,R) :-
    maplist(permutation,L,R).
```

It functions only in the special case where `L` is composed of lists and doesn't function when `L` is heterogeneous (atoms and lists).

Could you provide hints or elements of solution to do the right permutation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following modification should do:

```
permutation(X,X).

permutation(L,[T|Q]) :-
   dif(L,[T|Q]),
   select(T,L,L1),
   permutation(L1,Q).

allperm(L,R) :-
    maplist(permutation,L,R).
```

We extend the “identity” permutation to any Prolog term (first clause of `permutation`) and disallow it in the second clause (which can only be applied to lists anyway).

Comment: @Hana: doesn't it? I didn't check thoroughly, but with your example I get 72 distinct lists (which makes me think that it works on your example, at least). Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Apologies. Indeed, It functions perfectly. thanks Gniourf.